# convert slide made in bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

When I change it to bootstrap4, all the images are joined and they do not respect the width of 400% of the class #slide ul, the only thing I have to do is set the relative position to fixed, but the scroll and the other elements such as the page and the arrows are put behind,I don't want to use the .carousel class that comes in bootstrap4 because this project is even bigger and what I have done is delete several labels and elements so that my question is more concise.

```js
/* variables */
var item = 0;

var interrumpirCiclo=false;




var item = 0;
var itemPaginacion = $("#paginacion li");
var interrumpirCiclo = false;
var imgProducto = $(".imgProducto");
var titulos1 = $("#slide h1");
var titulos2 = $("#slide h2");
var titulos3 = $("#slide h3");
var btnVerProducto = $("#slide button");
var detenerIntervalo = false;
var toogle = false;

$("#slide ul li").css({"width":100/$("#slide ul li").length + "%"})
$("#slide ul").css({"width":$("#slide ul li").length*100 + "%"})



$(imgProducto[item]).animate({"top":-10 +"%", "opacity": 0},100)
$(imgProducto[item]).animate({"top":30 +"px", "opacity": 1},600)




$("#paginacion li").click(function(){

    item = $(this).attr("item")-1;

    movimientoSlide(item);

})



function avanzar(){

    if(item == $("#slide ul li").length -1){

        item = 0;

    }else{

        item++

    }

    interrumpirCiclo = true;

    movimientoSlide(item);

}

$("#slide #avanzar").click(function(){

    avanzar();

})

/*=============================================
RETROCEDER
=============================================*/

$("#slide #retroceder").click(function(){

    if(item == 0){

        item = $("#slide ul li").length -1;

    }else{

        item--

    }

    movimientoSlide(item);

})




function movimientoSlide(item){

    // http://easings.net/es

    $("#slide ul").animate({"left": item * -100 + "%"}, 1000)

    $("#paginacion li").css({"opacity":.5})

    $(itemPaginacion[item]).css({"opacity":1})

    interrumpirCiclo = true;

    
}



setInterval(function(){

    if(interrumpirCiclo){

        interrumpirCiclo = false;

    }else{

        if(!detenerIntervalo){

            avanzar();

        }

    }

},3000)

/*=============================================
APARECER FLECHAS
=============================================*/

$("#slide").mouseover(function(){

    $("#slide #retroceder").css({"opacity":1})
    $("#slide #avanzar").css({"opacity":1})

    detenerIntervalo = true;

})


$("#slide").mouseout(function(){

    $("#slide #retroceder").css({"opacity":0})
    $("#slide #avanzar").css({"opacity":0})

    detenerIntervalo = false;

})
```

```css
/* SLIDE*/
#slide{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
#slide ul{
  position:relative;/*en B4 funciona fixed*/
  width:400%;
  left:0%;
  margin:auto;
  height:auto;
  clear:both;
  display:table;
  padding:0px;
}

#slide ul li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}  

#slide ul li img{
  width: 100%;

  }

/* ====PAGINACION=== */
#slide #paginacion{
    position: relative;/*en B4 funciona fixed*/
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 12px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
#slide #paginacion li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .5;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #333;
}
#slide #paginacion li:first-child{
    opacity:1;
}



/*=============================================
ESCRITORIO GRANDE (xl revisamos en 1366px en adelante)
=============================================*/

@media (min-width:1200px){
    #slide #retroceder{
        top:45%;
        padding:40px 15px 40px 10px;
        font-size:22px;
    }
    #slide #avanzar{
        top:45%;
        padding:40px 10px 40px 15px;
        font-size:22px; 
    }
    #slide .slideOpciones h1{
        font-size: 50px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    #slide .slideOpciones h2{
         font-size:35px;
    }
    #slide .slideOpciones h3{
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    #slide .slideOpciones button{
        padding:10px; 
    }
    

}

/*=============================================
ESCRITORIO MEDIANO O TABLET HORIZONTAL (lg revisamos en 1024px)
=============================================*/

@media (max-width:1199px) and (min-width:992px){
    #slide #retroceder{
        top:45%;/*esto no se porq no funciona*/
        padding:40px 15px 40px 10px;
        font-size:18px;
    }
    #slide #avanzar{
        top:45%;
        padding:40px 10px 40px 15px;
        font-size:18px; 
    }
    #slide .slideOpciones h1{
        font-size: 35px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    #slide .slideOpciones h2{
         font-size:20px;
        /* display: none; */
    }
    #slide .slideOpciones h3{
        font-size: 15px;
        /* margin-bottom: -5px; */
    }
    #slide .slideOpciones button{
        padding:10px; 
    }
}

/*=============================================
ESCRITORIO PEQUEÑO O TABLET VERTICAL (md revisamos en 768px)
=============================================*/

@media (max-width:991px) and (min-width:768px){

    #slide #retroceder{
        top:35%;
        padding:30px 8px 30px 5px;
        font-size:14px; 
    }

    #slide #avanzar{
        top:35%;
        padding:30px 5px 30px 8px;
        font-size:14px; 
    }

    #slide .slideOpciones h1{
        font-size: 25px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    
    }

    #slide .slideOpciones h2{
        font-size:20px; 
    }

    #slide .slideOpciones h3{
        font-size: 15px;
        /* margin-bottom: -5px; */
    }

    #slide .slideOpciones button{
        padding:5px; 
    }

}

/*=============================================
MOVIL (sm revisamos en 320px) ==>revisalo en 576 y borras el 320
=============================================*/

@media (max-width:767px) and (min-width: 576px){

    
    #slide .flechas{
        display: none;
    }

    #slide .slideOpciones h1{
        font-size: 20px;
        

    }

    #slide .slideOpciones h2{
        display: none;
    }

    #slide .slideOpciones h3{
        font-size: 15px;
        /* margin-bottom: 15px; */
    }

    #slide .slideOpciones button{
        margin-top:5px;
        padding:5px 5px; 
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    }


/*=============================================
MOVIL pequeño (revisamos en 320px)
=============================================*/

@media (max-width:575px) {

    #slide .flechas{
        display: none;
    }
    #slide .slideOpciones h1{
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: -20px;
    }
    #slide .slideOpciones h2{
        display: none;
    }
    #slide .slideOpciones h3{
        font-size: 10px;
        margin-bottom: -5px;
    }
    #slide .slideOpciones button{
        padding:5px 5px; 
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}

/* ===FLECHAS== */
#slide .flechas{
    position: absolute;/*en B4 funciona fixed*/
    font-size:2em;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
}
#slide #retroceder{
    background: #666;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
#slide #avanzar{
    background: #666;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
#slide #retroceder:hover, #slide #avanzar:hover{
    background: #777;
}
#slide #retroceder:active, #slide #avanzar:active{
    background: #444;
}


ol{
    padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Como lo paso a Bootstrap 4</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="slide.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="slide.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" id="slide">
    <div class="row">
        <!--=====================================
        =            DIAPOSITIVAS            =
        ======================================-->
        <ul>
         <!-- SLIDE 1-->
       
            <li>
                <img src="https://cdn3.dibujos.net/dibujos/pintar/numero-1_163.png" alt="">

                
            </li>
             
             <!-- SLIDE 2-->
       
            <li>
                <img src="https://cdn3.dibujos.net/dibujos/pintar/numero-2_163.png" alt="">

                
            </li> 

            <!-- SLIDE 3-->
       
            <li>
                <img src="https://cdn3.dibujos.net/dibujos/pintar/numero-3_163.png" alt="">

                
            </li> 

            <!-- SLIDE 4-->
       
            <li>
                <img src="https://cdn3.dibujos.net/dibujos/pintar/numero-4_163.png" alt="">

                
            </li> 


        </ul>
        
        
        <!--====  End of DIAPOSITIVAS  ====-->
        
     
         <ol id="paginacion">

            <li item="1"><span class="fa fa-circle"></span></li>
            <li item="2"><span class="fa fa-circle"></span></li>
            <li item="3"><span class="fa fa-circle"></span></li>
            <li item="4"><span class="fa fa-circle"></span></li>

        </ol>   

        <!--=============================
        =            FLECHAS            =
        ==============================-->
        <div class="flechas" id="retroceder"><span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span></div>
        <div class="flechas" id="avanzar"><span class="fas fa-chevron-right"></span></div>
        
        
        <!--====  End of FLECHAS  ====-->
        
         
        
    </div>
</div>
     <script src="slide.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, solo borre la clase "row" del div, y funciona tambien en bootstrap 4, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

le quite la clase row al div de las diapositivas y funciona igual al bootstrap3
a #slide ul
lo mantuve con position:relative
y a #slide #paginacion
lo cambié a  position: absolute.

eso es todo,funciona igual q en bootstrap3.